# RHEL: man page for interface configuration files

Tags: rhel, man, network-interface

How to get the `man` page for `ifcfg-$Interface` files? Something like `man 5 $Keyword` for `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`. Is there not a `man` page? Is the keyword wrong?

```
RHEL:~# cat /etc/os-release | egrep "^NAME=|^VERSION="
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.0 (Maipo)"
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# man --version
man 2.6.3
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# man 5 ifcfg
No manual entry for ifcfg in section 5
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# whatis ifcfg
ifcfg (8)            - simplistic script which replaces ifconfig IP managment
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# man -k ifcfg
ifcfg (8)            - simplistic script which replaces ifconfig IP managment
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# 
RHEL:~# file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3: ASCII text
RHEL:~#
```

Works fine on SUSE:

```
SUSE:~# cat /etc/os-release | egrep "^NAME=|^VERSION="
NAME=openSUSE
VERSION="13.1 (Bottle)"
SUSE:~# 
SUSE:~# 
SUSE:~# man --version
man 2.6.3
SUSE:~# 
SUSE:~# 
SUSE:~# whatis ifcfg
ifcfg (5)            - common elements of network interface configuration
SUSE:~# SUSE:~# man 5 ifcfg
SUSE:~# 
SUSE:~# 
SUSE:~# man -k ifcfg
ifcfg (5)            - common elements of network interface configuration
ifcfg-bonding (5)    - interface bonding configuration
ifcfg-bridge (5)     - ethernet bridge interface configuration
ifcfg-tunnel (5)     - network tunnel interface configuration
ifcfg-vlan (5)       - virtual LAN interface configuration
ifcfg-wireless (5)   - wireless LAN network interface configuration
SUSE:~# 
SUSE:~# 
SUSE:~# file /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-enp0s3 
/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-enp0s3: ASCII text
SUSE:~#
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found it in manual docs using `find / -name *ifcfg*`

Please use `man 5 nm-settings-ifcfg-rh`.

It includes most comprehensive documents.
I have spent 1 hour to find it......HAHA

Answer (score 9):

There doesn't seem to be a manpage for the interfaces config files in RHEL but the documentation can be found in:

```
/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysconfig.txt
```

Look for the sections describing files `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface-name>`

Also in your example the command `whatis ifcfg` returns

```
ifcfg (8) - simplistic script which replaces ifconfig IP managment
```

As you can see it refers to "section 8" - *Admin tools and commands* - and you can open the manpage with:

```
man 8 ifcfg
```

But be aware that it's not the manpage describing the sysconfig files `ifcfg-<interface-name>`. Instead it's a manpage for a command `/sbin/ifcfg` which is likely not what you want.

Comment: rpm -d initscripts

Comment: Had to mark the new answer from _May 18 at 18:18_ as correct. However, if I could give +10 points, then I would give it to **MLu**.

Answer (score 3):

RHEL documentation for network-scripts (not strictly the man page you requested, but might help)

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html

Answer (score 1):

If the `NetworkManager` package is installed on CentOS/RHEL v7, then `man -k ifcfg` prints :

```
# man -k ifcfg
ifcfg (8)            - simplistic script which replaces ifconfig IP management
nm-settings-ifcfg-rh (5) - Description of ifcfg-rh settings plugin
```

Then, to view the `ifcfg-*` documentation, you can type `man nm-settings-ifcfg-rh` straightaway.